# How to convert PDF to WORD in c#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, ms-word

Does anyone know a .NET component to convert PDF to Word or RTF programmatically? I don't want to use OCR and Adobe dependent solutions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question has already been asked here, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192400/does-anyone-know-of-a-way-to-easily-convert-a-pdf-to-a-docx-format-programmatical

Comment: And about 4,000 other places. This question gets asked about three times a week. Try doing a search for "PDF", "Word" and "conversion".

Comment: I just did that. It brought me here.

Answer (score 5):

I tried several libraries:

- PDF Focus .NET:  https://sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-focus/index.php
- Aspose.PDF: https://products.aspose.com/pdf/net
- Gembox: https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document
- Spire.PDF: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-net-introduce.html
- considered also using Word via COM automation to open and save to pdf programmatically.

Among all of them I liked PDF Focus .NET best of all, and I will explain why:

1. They try to keep the structure of the document EDITABLE, so that
   when I try to continue editing the text, the paragraph will be
   smoothly prolonged. Other libraries try to do a
   "minimalistic" approach by inserting absolute positioned shapes, so
   that if you continue editing the text, it overlaps with the next
   piece of text.
2. They all do their best to recognize tables, so
   that tables in the output document will be REAL TABLES, but not a
   collection of shapes and texts with absolute positioning (as
   produced by other libraries).

A customer of ours is evaluating different libraries, and I will recommend PDF Focus .NET first of all.

P.S. I AM NOT INVOLVED IN ANY KIND OF RELATIONSHIP WITH THIS SOFTWARE PRODUCER.  As a former .NET developer I simply see a high quality components which really work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use [PDF Focus](http://www.sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-focus/index.php).

Nice and easy.

**EDIT**: And also

[How to convert DOC into other formats using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/convertdocintootherformat.aspx)

http://dotnetf1.blogspot.com/2008/07/convert-word-doc-into-pdf-using-c-code.html

Comment: how to get the invitation from the blog author ?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview). It's a simple .NET component that enables you to manipulate and convert all kinds of document files.

Answer (score -1):

You should have read this: [C# and PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090154/convert-pdf-to-word-in-java). There are methods to convert, like beforementioned PDF Focus but be warned: it is buggy, and crashy process. PDF is not intended to be PC-readable.

Comment: We are preparing the new engine for PDF Focus .Net right now, this will be version 2.0, completely improved. It will appear soon.

Comment: @Maximus That is a great job (I looked into PDF, I know). The flaw is in PDF standart itself. e-mail me, and I will find you several files, that would break you component.

Comment: Nowadays (2016) [**PDF Focus .Net**](http://sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-focus/index.php) became a strong and the component in the prime of life :).  We are with pleasure ready to look at any complex PDF files at support@sautinsoft.com.